# Remove character from string

Tags: linux, xslt

i have one variable $serviceName = "ZSMeter". i have to remove "S" from this string and get "ZMeter". how i can solve it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pardon my xsl...
but hope it ll help

`<xsl:variable name="frst" select="substring-before($serviceName,'S')" />
<xsl:variable name="after" select="substring-after($serviceName,'S')" />
<xsl:variable name=serviceName select="concat($frst,$after)" />`

Answer (score 2):

```
translate($serviceName, 'S', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
concat(
    substring($serviceName, 1, 1),
    substring($serviceName, 3)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace($serviceName, '^ZSMeter$', 'ZMeter')` in case you're with XSLT 2.0.